# CodeContracts falsely flags missing precondition that exists already in base constructor

Tags: c#, code-contracts, constructor-chaining

Say I have the following class hierarchy:

```
public class FooBase
{
    private readonly object _obj;

    protected FooBase(object obj)
    {
        Contract.Requires(obj != null);
        _obj = obj;
    }
}

public class Foo : FooBase
{
    public Foo(object obj) : base(obj)
    {
    }
}
```

When I compile, I get the following CodeContracts error for `Foo`:

```
Error   12  CodeContracts: Missing precondition in an externally visible method. Consider adding Contract.Requires(obj != null); for parameter validation
```

Is there any way to make CodeContracts recognise that the validation already happens in the base class?

Comment: I think the message is accurate though; you can't see the base ctor, only the subclasses, and the subclass ctor has no contract.  I suspect it'd be the same if you were calling a base method from a public method on a subclass.  Methods don't "inherit" contracts.

Comment: You would have a point if `FooBase` had a parameterless constructor. But given that it doesn't, it is impossible for the base constructor `Contract.Requires` not to be called. Therefore, I return to my original question...

Comment: But that's not how contracts work.  The analyzer only looks at the method in isolation, it doesn't take into account other method it calls when its determine pre- and post-conditions.

Comment: Fair enough - I take your argument on-board w.r.t. regular methods. But perhaps the authors should think to change that to take account of constructor chaining. It seems to me something of a special case. I have no desire to mindlessly repeat code unnecessarily, just to make the static checker happy.

Comment: Well really what is the difference between a ctor and normal method (except the rules for invoking them)?  Why wouldn't they also do this for other methods?  I don't think what you're suggesting is feasible with design by contract; subtypes are actually allowed to weaken pre-conditions, which wouldn't be possible if you inherited the conditions from any method you called. A ctor should also be able to weaken preconditions as well. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract

Comment: Well, thanks for your input. To conclude, I will just say that I did `Consider adding Contract.Requires(obj != null)`, had a prolonged discussion about it on SO, decided not to and ignore the warnings then...

Comment: Ok, but be aware that others coming along won't be sure if you purposefully meant to weaken the precondition or if the warning really is an oversight.  Personally I hate finding code like that were I don't know if the method should handle null and doesn't properly, or if the person just forgot to add a precondition.  And that's kinda why I like CC so much, as the contracts are meant to ensure you're documenting this stuff.

Comment: Much later update - I got sick of the warnings a long time ago and caved and duplicated the CCs everywhere that the static checker wanted. If you can't beat 'em...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not.
Your Foo is calling FooBase(obj) without the proper requires.

```
public class FooBase
{
    private readonly object _obj;

    protected FooBase(object obj)
    {
        Contract.Requires(obj != null);
        _obj = obj;
    }
}

public class Foo : FooBase
{
    public Foo(object obj) : base(obj)
    {
        Contract.Requires(obj != null);
    }
}
```

would be the only way to fix this issue.